# How can I iterate through children of multiple push keys in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I are trying to retrive lecture information. The information is structured like this:[image]

I am trying to store details of each lecture in an array.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through the children try this:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lectures").child("Saturday,March 03");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String batchname=datas.child("batch_name").getValue().toString();
          //etc
     }
  }
    @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
  });
```

the `for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren())` will let you iterate inside the push keys.

`dataSnapshot.getChildren()` will give you the direct children, which are the push keys in this case. Then using the for loop you will be able to access the data inside these keys